# MySQL, how can I group on group_concat?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Here is my current query (confidential data replaced and where clauses removed for simplicity):

```
select a.id, group_concat(v.value) from asset a, values v where a.id=v.id group by a.case_id;
```

The current results appear as:

a.id   v.value
123    a,b
234    a
456    a,b,c
789    d,e
237    a

What I want it to do is group by and count the results of the group_concat, so it should look like:

v.value    count
a,b            1
a                2
a,b,c         1
d,e            1

I have tried unsuccessfully to group on the field name I give to the group_concat, it keeps on saying 'unable to group by 'name'

I have to do this directly in the query not in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you want case_id to appear in the result set?

Comment: my mistake, it should have been group by a.id not a.case_id. I don't need the individual id in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT gc_values
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.id
            , GROUP_CONCAT(v.value) gc_values
         FROM asset a
         JOIN `values` v 
           ON v.id = a.id
        GROUP
           BY a.id
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY gc_values;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, your code appears to count the number of results for each individual value of the group_concat. What I want is the grouped results of the group_concat. In other words, how many times does just 'a' appear, or how may times do we have 'a,b,c'

Comment: Er, no. I'm pretty sure this fulfils the spec. !?!

Comment: Interesting. However, I'm getting a syntax error near ' COUNT(*). That's even when I copy your exact code

Comment: Oh yeah - values is a reserved word in 5.6

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
select grouped_values, count(*) from [subselect aliasing group_concat] group by grouped_values
```